# WiX installer does not work on vs 2012

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I want to create a setup installer for my application.  I have downloaded WiX 3.6 and installed it on vs 2012.

1. Create simple winform application
2. Add WiX setup project to my solution
3. Right click on reference and add my winform application to setup's reference
4. I build solution and go to debug directory in setup project and run SetupProject1.exe.msi it does not work and closes the installer dialog without any error.

Go back to setup project

1. Right click on setup project and select properties
2. On installer tab > output type, change it to executablefile.exe
3. Build it and go to debug and run SetupProject1.exe - still does not work

What is wrong? This is my setup project product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Natiloos" UpgradeCode="cfc2f4dd-2da5-49e2-9099-96968d75aaa4">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is  already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and     the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->

        <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

How can I get the installer to build correctly?

Comment: What version of WiX are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your installer is not installing anything. Adding your project as a reference to the installer does not mean the installer will include your projects output. In your setup project you have:

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and     the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
    <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->

    <!-- </Component> -->
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

You need to add the files...i.e. uncomment the `<Component></Component>` tags and add your files manually. It's good to have one `<Component>` tag per file.

Example:

```
 <Component Id="MyProgram.exe" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
      <File Id="MyProgram.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="Path_To_Output_Folder\MyProgram.exe" />
 </Component>
```

Comment: Is there a way in VS2012 to automate this at all? Or are you forced to enter in XML?

Comment: You can automate with the tool Heat: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm. Generally speaking I enter it manually for my projects, but then use Heat if something is being developed and changing constantly, such as help files or other supplemental content. Note that you *used* to be able to run heat on projects but that was buggy so they removed that functionality. I typically write a wrapper that calls Heat and then tweaks the resulting xml to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

WiX projects of the type that you are describing produce MSI files, with the .msi extension.  These installers are not run directly, rather then are run using `msiexec.exe`.  Windows explorer does this for you by default when you double click on them, however you can explicitly call `msiexec` using a command like the following

```
msiexec MyInstaller.msi
```

Note that MSI files are completely different from executables - changing the output name of your setup produce to have an .exe extension, or renaming the file to have an .exe extension won't work.

If you want to produce an .exe based installer then what you need is a bootstrapper.  WiX has one called Burn, however if I were you I would worry about making an MSI that works first and *then* worry about creating an executable bootstrapper.

Comment: @motevallizadeh Define "does not work".  At the moment your installer isn't going to do anything except add an extry to the add/remove programs list - you haven't specified what it is you want to install.

Comment: look at:http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_votive_project.htm

Comment: @motevallizadeh You missed the part of that guide where you add the `<File />` element to your `<Component />`

Comment: I think the problem is the very bad documentation of WiX. The tutorial describes his approach as the way to go.